# Full width horizontal navigation and Foundation framework

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to make horizontal navigation using css tables. When I use only plain HTML and CSS it works correctly but it doesn't when foundation css is included. It is left aligned and not full width. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Plain code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNgXPo

Foundation CSS included - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdEJOm

HTML

```
<div class="row contain-to-grid">
      <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                  <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#">asdf</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">asdasdasdasdasd asdasd</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">qweqweqwe</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">qwe</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">qwe</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="#">sdpofispdof</a></li> 
                  </ul> 
            </section> 
      </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top-bar .top-bar-section {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.top-bar .top-bar-section ul {
    display: table-row;
    width: inherit;
}
.top-bar .top-bar-section li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px dotted red;
}
.top-bar .top-bar-section a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.top-bar-section ui li` is the problem child here. Foundation forces it to `float: left;` when the `min-width: 40.063em` is triggered.

If you override the `float: left;` it'll work.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) .top-bar-section ul li {
  float:left;
}
```

So change your `.top-bar .top-bar-section li` css to include the new float value:

```css
.top-bar .top-bar-section li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  float: none;
}
```

This will work if your custom stylesheet is being loaded after foundation as it overrides the media call.